# How to get current url and get code from it in PHP

Tags: php, url

Im making an email verification system on PHP in cPanel, and when i press register, it sends an email to me with a link like this "../verified.php?code=1cbb402a59e8ec26dac0", i would need to get the full link and would have to chop it so it leaves me with just the code "1cbb402a59e8ec26dac0" so i can check if the code exists in database and then verify the account.

So from this

../verified.php?code=1cbb402a59e8ec26dac0

To This

"1cbb402a59e8ec26dac0

Purchasing the hostings for the first time fried my brains, so would be thankful if anyone could help me,

Comment: If you're doing this in php on the page this link loads, you can use `$code = $_GET['code'] ?? '';`

Comment: You don’t need to “chop” anything, PHP parses the query string for you already, and the parameters are accessible via $_GET.

Comment: Also, please dont use unrelated tags

Answer (score 1):

For getting the text after the `code:` in the link, you can use the PHP `$_GET` function. You can use this code in your `verified.php` to get the text after `code:`

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
  $Data=$_GET['code'];
}
else{
echo "Invalid Email Verification";
?>
```

Now the part after the `code=` gets stored in the variable `Data`.
You can change that to your desired variable.
Sometimes even when the `code` is set, it might be empty, so to check that, the `empty()` function in PHP can be used.
You can add this code to your `verified.php`:

```php
<?php
if (empty($Data))
{
  echo "Invalid Verification ID";
}
else
{
  echo "Email Verification Success";
  //your other codes to update it on the server
}
?>
```

Comment: Correct, but note that you should protect against cases where `$_GET` doesnt contain a `code` index in which case this code would emit an "Undefined index" notice

Comment: I have changed the answer, hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, thats not what I mean. Calling `$Data= $_GET['code'];`  will emit an "Undefined index" notice if someone hits that page _without_ a "code" parameter. So if they go to `/verified.php`, this code will throw a notice. Its generally good practice to write such code in a way that prevents access to potentially undefined indexes, see TimBrownlaw's answer as an example.

Comment: Ya, I have edited the answer now, I also added `empty()` as sometimes even when the `code` is set, there can be no value in it which may lead to an error. I have improved the answer anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have chosen to pass parameters which will be available in the global `$_GET[]` (as opposed to `$_POST[]`).

So in your verified.php you will need to examine for the presence of $_GET['code'] and take the appropriate action.

Using `$code = $_GET['code'];` is very bad as you need to qualify it.

**At a minimum** you would need to...

```
<?php

// Ternary to give $code a value to prevent undefined variable error.
$code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : NULL; 

if($code === NULL){
  // error
} else {
  // Check its a valid code and take the appropriate action.
}
```

Comment: +1 for protecting against the "Undefined index" notice. As a side note, if the OP is using php7, that can be simplified to `$code = $_GET['code'] ?? '';` :)

Comment: I see someone has downvoted this, I can't imagine why...

Comment: Cheers Wesley, who knows... Probably as I've gone old school and haven't used filter_input() yet.